# What do you call a person who has basic knowledge or some basic experience in some programming language?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am proficient in ReactJs (which is a Javascript framework for creating web applications). I want to mention that I have basic knowledge, and some experience, in other programming languages as well. This is for a resume so needs to be in a short and concise way (apart from React).

I am trying to find another word for 'beginner' as this word seems too basic. I tried finding various synonyms for the word but I am not content with any of the available synonyms.

Could anyone suggest a good phrase or word for it?

Comment: You state that the "various synonyms" are not suitable, what exactly do you need this word/phrase to mean that the synonyms lack?

Comment: @KillingTime As dubious mentioned in the answer, I actually need a one-word referring to such a phrase. For example, proficient suits as I am experienced in the language. But in another language, I am a novice. I want some formal word that is kind of midway of too novice and proficient.

Comment: Your experience level might be: Novice, Advanced Beginner, Competent, Proficient or Expert.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I think I will go with either intermediate or Advanced Beginner.

Comment: A *"gentleman amateur"*?

Comment: "What do you call a person who has basic knowledge or some basic experience in some programming language?" *Dangerous.*

Comment: I like to use the word 'conversant' as I would with a natural language, because it implies many of the same qualities: it implies that I don't shy away from the language and am happy to use it, I can understand it and contribute meaningfully, though I may not know everything, I know enough to know what I don't know and the right questions to ask and the write terminology to use when I don't know something, etc.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I agree :D

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- *I am also familiar with Rust and Go*
- *I have some familiarity with...*
- *I have also worked with...*
- *I have some experience with...*
- *In the past I have worked with...*

Comment: I have seen in most of the sample resumes `I` being avoided. Most of the profile summary begins with something like `Self-motivated and cheerful customer service professional with 2+ years of experience helping customers navigate websites and resolving product and service issues. ` I want to include something like `Proficient in ReactJs and Javascript. Have some experience in Rust and Go.`. So, just like word proficient, some single-word for familiarity and experience seem better in this context but I am not quite sure what word to use.

Comment: If you can't use "*I*" In a document designed to sell yourself, where can you? If you don't want it to be first-person, try: "*Proficient in ReactJs and Javascript. Additional experience in Rust and Go.*"